# Laravel Query builder select same table same column with diferent condition

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, query-builder

I have 2 tables for example "User" and "Courses".
I want select users which has pass two courses.

```
user               
id username
1 John
2 Jane

courses
id name user_id
1 course-1 1
2 course-2 1
3 course-1 2
```

I use:

```
(new User)->join('courses', 'courses.user_id', '=', 'user.id')
->whereIn('courses.name', ['course-1','course-2'])
```

But this query return 2 users not 1 (only john). I want whereIn return AND connection not OR connection.

I want like this:

```
 SELECT * from user 
    join courses as c1 on c1.user_id = user.id
    join courses as c2 on c2.user_id = user.id
    where c1.name = 'course-1' and c2.name = 'course-2'
```

how it will be in Laravel?

Comment: Don't you mean `c2.user_id = user.id`?

Comment: oh sorry Yes. thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
User::join('courses as c1', 'c1.user_id', '=', 'user.id')
    ->join('courses as c2', 'c2.user_id', '=', 'user.id')
    ->where('c1.name', 'course-1')
    ->where('c2.name', 'course-2')
```

BTW: You should use [Eloquent relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships) for situations like this.